# A classification of a singularity via Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to classify the singularities of

$$f(z)=z \sin(z+\frac{1}{z})$$

$f$ has a singularity at $z_0=0$. I need to compute the Laurent series expansion of $\sin(z+\frac{1}{z})$. Using the identity

$$z+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{(z-i)(z+i)}{z}$$

I get

$$\sin(z+\frac{1}{z})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} (\frac{(z-i)(z+i)}{z})^{2n+1}$$

which doesn't appear to be very useful.

I also have

$$\sin(z+\frac{1}{z})=\sin(\frac{1}{z}) \cos(z)+ \sin(z) \cos(\frac{1}{z})$$.

But this requires me to compute two Cauchy products which seems rather unwieldy. Is there an easier way to find the Laurent series?

Comment: Do you want the whole series or just the $1/z$ coefficient?

Comment: Factoring the sum the way you did was not the best way to handle it. Leave it as $z + \frac{1}{z}$, use binomial series then swap the order of the summation. This will give a formula for the residue. Alternatively, using Euler's formula and turning the sin into complex exponentials might be easier to prove that the pole is an essential singularity.

Comment: Easiest way, I think, is "$z + \frac{1}{z}$ attains all values in $\mathbb{C}\setminus D_R(0)$ on $D_\epsilon(0) \setminus \{0\}$, hence $\sin \bigl(z + \frac{1}{z}\bigr)$ attains all complex values there. Thus $\sin \bigl(z + \frac{1}{z}\bigr)$ has an essential singularity at $0$. Multiplying with a meromorphic function that does not identically vanish cannot make an essential singularity inessential."